# c++ properties implementing functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

Supposing a general player that will notify certain events to certain objects of classes. I create a base class with some virtual functions guaranteed to exist in the derived:

```
class PlayEventsReceiver{

    virtual void StartPlay()=0;
    virtual void StopPlay()=0;  
};
```

I would derive from PlayEventsReceiver the classes interested in such "signals"

```
class FooPlayer:public PlayEventsReceiver{

    void StartPlay(){...}
    void StopPlay(){...}
};
```

But if I wanted, rather than inheriting, implementing the signaling mechanism as a property, like this:

```
class BarPlayer{

    PlayEventsReceiver receiver; 

};
```

Is it possible to implement the pure virtual functions somehow inside the class BarPlayer in a clean way and not creating intermediate derived classes?

Comment: No because you can't instantiate a virtual class, so you have to create an intermediate derived class.

Comment: If you could come up with a way to *"implement the pure virtual functions somehow inside the class BarPlayer"* how would it be more *clean* than simply making `BarPlayer` inherit the *interface* and supply its own implementations?

Comment: @Galik, I was just experimenting a concept new to me, "Composition over inheritance" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a *derived class* then the compiler has nowhere to put its functions. If you are looking for something *clean* then creating an explicit *derived class* is probably as clean as it gets.

You can't escape the fact that *somewhere* you need to supply the function implementations.

However, it seems you can do this *anonymously* by creating an *unnamed class/struct*. But it is not avoiding creating a *derived class* because an anonymous *derived class* is still being created:

```
// public interface so I use struct
struct PlayEventsReceiver {

    virtual void StartPlay() = 0;
    virtual void StopPlay() = 0;
};

class BarPlayer {

public:
    struct : PlayEventsReceiver {

        void StartPlay() override
        {
            std::cout << "Start Play\n";
        }
        void StopPlay() override
        {
            std::cout << "Stop Play\n";
        }
    } receiver;

};

int main()
{
    BarPlayer bp;

    bp.receiver.StartPlay();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. If I am not missing anything, there's not a clear way to access the outer class, only passing a pointer to the container in the constructor of the inner making things a more complicated than simply inheriting the PlayEventsReceiver.